# FATAL: Errno::EACCES when trying to copy files using Ruby and Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've confirmed that I have permissions on the local box. Here is my default.rb in my Chef cookbook:

```
ruby_block "Copy Oracle Files" do
    block do
        require 'fileutils'
        FileUtils.cp_r("#{node["server_files"]}","c:\\chef-tmp")
    end
    action :create
end
```

Here is the server_files dir:  `default["server_files"] = "\\\\winmomfs1\\3rdParty\\Oracle Client\\Oracle_11g\\win64_11gR2_client.zip"`

And upon running chef-client on the node, I get:

```
[2013-12-20T12:51:45-05:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2013-12-20T12:51:45-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-12-20T12:51:45-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-12-20T12:51:45-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2013-12-20T12:51:45-05:00] FATAL: Errno::EACCES: ruby_block[Copy Oracle Files] (oracle::default line 9) had an error: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - \\winmomfs1\3rdParty
\Oracle Client\Oracle_11g\win64_11gR2_client.zip
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: `Permission denied` your chef user does not have the priviliges to access that file

Comment: How do you make it so that your chef users have access to network shares?

Comment: That depends on YOUR system.

Comment: I mean, my LDAP user has permissions to access the share, so I'm confused on why the validation is trying to use my chef user account?

Comment: The issue was that I was trying to run this over telnet because I hadn't setup ssh yet - obviously, that didn't work out.

Comment: Idea is to check that your path is valid, i.e. exists